# Is this unsafe to use in C?

Tags: c, char, c-strings, strcat

Hello I've come upon a problem. Im not very experienced in C.

I am trying to concatenate one char to my path variable.

But when I am running this line of code my other string variable gets "overriden" or behaves weird afterwards. When commented out everything works normally. I don't want to post the whole code here inseat I am just curios if this single line is somehow unsafe to run.

```
strcat(path, "/");
```

I also tried:

//edit i actually tried strcat but later strncat copied the line while reversing the changes//

```
char temp = '/';
strncat(path, &temp);
```

I am stuck wayyy to long on this so maybe someone can help.

Comment: That can't compile. `strncat` wants three arguments. Read the man page https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncat. It even mentions why things might behave weird/unpredictable after using it incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, it's unsafe.  You need storage that's big enough to hold the original string plus _more_ characters.   Without showing what 'path' is, we have to assume it only has enough room for the string it contains.

Comment: In most cases, `snprintf` is much better to use than `strncat`. In this case, you could also use `char *p = &path[strlen(path)]; *p++ = '/'; *p++ = '\0';` but only if the current length is at least 2 smaller than the maximum length.

Comment: How is the `path` variable defined?

Comment: @printf oh my thanks for the question, I looked at the declaration and because I am refactoring a very long path, the initial size is to small. At first I thought it was enough, but it was slightly too little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the function `strncat` has three parameters

```
char *strncat(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2, size_t n);
```

So this call

```
strncat(path, "/");
```

will not compile.

Apart from this error this code snippet

```
char temp = '/';
strncat(path, &temp);
```

has one more error that is the expression `&temp` does not point to a string.

You can append a character to a string only if the array containing the string has enough space to accommodate one more character. For example you may not change a string literal.

If the array containing the string has enough memory to accommodate  the character `'/'` then you can write

```
strcat( path, "/" );
```

or

```
size_t n = strlen( path );
path[n++] = '/';
path[n] = '\0';
```

Or as `@Barmar` correctly pointed in his comment to the answer you could use `strncat` the following way

```
char temp = '/';
strncat(path, &temp, 1);
```

Comment: I suspect what he's really trying to do is `strncat(path, &temp, 1)`. Then it doesn't care if there's a null terminator.

Comment: Yeah was trying to do that, thanks for the detailed answer! I appreciate your effort :)